# How to implement mmap for bar0

Tags: c++, linux-device-driver, pci-e

I'm trying to write my own Linux PCIe driver. I would like to write my `mmap` function so that it maps bar0, I realize I can do this without writing a driver but I'm doing this mostly for learning purposes.

My first question is why would you need to implement `mmap` if you can `mmap` bar0 without any driver development?

My second question is why is my `mmap` not working?

Here is my `mmap` code and the userspace app I use to access it

```
static int dma_proxy_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{

if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_pgoff,vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,vma->vm_page_prot))
{
return -EAGAIN;
}
printk(KERN_ALERT "mmap done\n");
return 0;
}
```

and here is my user space code

```
int main()
{

 int proxy_fd;
 int *MyMmap;
 proxy_fd = open("/dev/scull", O_RDWR);
 MyMmap = (int*)mmap(0,32, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, proxy_fd, 0);
if (MyMmap == MAP_FAILED) {
printf("mmap failed");
}
  MyMmap[0] = 10;
  printf ("Decimals: %d\n", MyMmap[0]);

}
```

I know it's not working correctly because my pcie card is designed to write a different value regardless of what I send to it to write which I've verified is working by mmaping to resource0 of that board.

Comment: No mmap succeeds but the values I read from MyMmap are not what was written to it by my fpga pcie card

Comment: You perhaps need to call `memremap()` instead of your approach. To say more you may provide an output of `lspci -n -vv -s <BDF_of_FPGA_device>`